# Does this LCS algo generate all the CS or only all the LCSs?

Tags: dynamic-programming, recursion, backtracking

The Wikipedia article on LCS has an algorithm that backtracks all the LCS strings. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Reading_out_all_LCSs) link redirects to the desired bulletin in the article. The C table in the backtrackAll function is pre-calculated, if you go up a tad bit. C[i][j] stores the LCSLength for given str1[1...i], str2[1...j].

[image]
*(screenshot, for a quicker reference)*

1. My understanding is that it generates **all** the **common sequences** since either or both *if* conditions at the end are satisfied, which runs the program for the sub-cases. Once the last letters are matched, every string upto that point (with the *current* X[i] as the last letter) is printed.

I somewhere fail to digest the algorithm properly and completely. An explanation might help me very much.

2. In the penultimate *if*, does changing writing the piece of code as  *R := R $\cup$ backtrackAll(C, X, Y, i, j-1)* (instead of  R := backtrackAll(C, X, Y, i, j-1)) change anything? I feel that it doesn't, given it's a top down approach and it only unions with the empty set R = {} above. Note that R is already defined above and the *if* is reached only after going through that empty set definition step, which rules out the possibility of having an error output.

Comment: Have you tried programming the algorithm and checking some of your suspicions?

Comment: I see the exact same code already available [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-longest-common-subsequence-set-2-printing/?ref=rp) and it only prints the LCS and not all the CS strings, which means my understanding (as in the first bullet) seems invalid. I still don't know why.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Could you please give me a reason/hint for this?

Comment: The answer to your second question is: it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is being sloppy. The procedure returns all LCSs of $X[1..i]$ and $Y[1..j]$, which corresponds to $C[i,j]$. It should mention that in order to obtain all LCSs, we need to set $i=m$ and $j=n$.

If $X[i] = Y[j]$, then every LCS of $X[1..i]$ and $Y[1..j]$ is obtained by taking an LCS of $X[1..i-1]$ and $Y[1..j-1]$, and adding to it $X[i] = Y[j]$.

If $X[i] \neq Y[j]$, then every LCS of $X[1..i]$ and $Y[1..j]$ must be either an LCS of $X[1..i-1]$ and $Y[1..j]$, or an LCS of $X[1..i]$ and $Y[1..j-1]$ (or both). If $C[i-1,j] > C[i,j-1]$, then only the former are LCSs of $X[1..i]$ and $Y[1..j]$. If $C[i-1,j] < C[i,j-1]$, then only the latter are LCSs of $X[1..i]$ and $Y[1..j]$. If $C[i-1,j] = C[i,j-1]$, then both types are LCSs of $X[1..i]$ and $Y[1..j]$.

This recursive procedure could count the same sequence more than once — this happens for example for the arrays $ab$ and $ac$, where $a$ will be reached twice.